# How to insert training data into spacy standalone NER trainer?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, named-entity-recognition, spacy

My aim to train standalone NER with the help of spacy.
Spacy provides [standalone ner trainer](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/examples/train_ner_standalone.py)

which can help to save model and load it later into the nlp pipeline.

I have prepared training data which in the following give format.

```
MUST,      O
have,       O
experience, U-technology
as,         O
a,          O
translator, O
, ,         O
editor,     U-technology
,,          O
interpreter,U-technology
,,          O
or,         O
writer,     U-technology
```

but i am not quite getting  way into to insert it as they give in their [integrated ner](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/examples/training/train_ner.py) with spacy

Answer (score 0):

Try going through the documentation. They've provided everything in the new and updated version.